# Module imports work in PyCharm, don't work in Python IDLE

Tags: python

Here is the file structure of my project:

```
data
front_end_ui
- __init__.py
- ui.py

quizlib
- __init__.py
- classes.py
- data_structure.py
- quiz.py
- student.py
```

Okay, aside from whether this is good programming or not ('tis likely the flying spaghetti monster) the program runs from ui.py, and in PyCharm, the import from quizlib works:

[All fine in PyCharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZraRx.png)

however in IDLE:

[Import failed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRa3u.png)

One of the first things as you can see from ui.py's code that happens is that stuff is imported from quizlib's __init__.py (just a couple of absolute directory names that are worked out before the whole program runs, because for the life of me I could not get relative change directory things to work).

Except it doesn't in IDLE. The only way I'm able to get it to work is to copy the entirety of quizlib into front_end_ui. (considering how I coded it I'm not quite sure why it works when I do that) Which if I'm not able to work out why will be an acceptable solution, but the explanation provided along with this project is better off keeping quizlib where it is.

Can somebody please explain this behaviour? For reference, I am using Python 3.4.3, and I'll provide any further details if needed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of problem is always due to PyCharm adding project path to PYTHONPATH.

[image]

Un-check those options and run again. Results would be the same.

Comment: Okay, is there any way to get this to work the other way round? Getting IDLE to run it correctly on another computer? Or should I just stick with moving quizlib about?

Comment: @user3025433 You could add path manually to `sys.path`, this is what PyCharm does.

Comment: Ah, thanks very much. I have everything working in a precarious position right now, and that's what I get for solving everything through good old trial-and-Does-it-work-now? but I just need to be able to have a folder to present to the examiners and say: This works. I'm not quite 100% sure how, but it does.

Comment: @user3025433 How can I help?

Comment: It's nothing, in ui.py I just got it to change directory to parent folder, append that directory to the sys.path, and cd back into front_end_ui, so everything seems to work now. Three lines of code solved my problem.