# How do I access the modules in PyCharm in my IDLE?

Tags: python, module, pycharm, python-idle

I am trying to access my modules in **PyCharm** in my **Python IDLE** but it shows me an error

This is my code

```
from termcolor import colored
print(colored('Testing', 'red', attrs=['bold']))
```

But this shows me a error in **IDLE** But this same code works like a breeze in **Pycharm**
here is the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'termcolor'
```

I've gone to this link [Module imports work in PyCharm, don't work in Python IDLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36618749/module-imports-work-in-pycharm-dont-work-in-python-idle)

Someone else also has the same question but the answers din't help me

Am i doing any thing wrong?

I am using python version --3.7
In Windows 7

If you need any information i will give you..

Thanks

Comment: This all depends on where your modules are stored, and what the current working directory is.

Comment: how do I check that and How do i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

> [Module imports work in PyCharm, don't work in Python IDLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36618749/module-imports-work-in-pycharm-dont-work-in-python-idle)

as laike9m said,

> This kind of problem is always due to PyCharm adding project path to
> PYTHONPATH.

```
# importing module
import sys
  
# appending a path
sys.path.append('C:/Users/Vanshi/Desktop')
  
# printing all paths
sys.path
```

this will help you

you can see more

> When a module(a module is a python file) is imported within a Python
> file, the interpreter first searches for the specified module among
> its built-in modules. If not found it looks through the list of
> directories(a directory is a folder that contains related modules)
> defined by sys.path.
> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sys-path-in-python/